# Can't get data for req.body with mean stack

Tags: javascript, angular

Hey I can't seem to get any results whilst using the req.body. Trying to get out the data from my mongodbdatabase to json format Here is my code:

My server file:

```
app.get('/api/category/posts', (req, res) => {
    Post.find({ categoryId: req.body._id }, function(err, posts) {
        res.json(posts);
    });
});
```

Service file:

```
getPosts(_id): Observable<Post[]>{
            return this.http.get<Post[]>(this.apiUrl +"/category/posts");
              }
```

component.ts

```
this.appService.getPosts(_id)
    .subscribe(data =>this.posts=data);
```

Comment: are you sure that you need get instead of post?

Comment: your api method is get method and you want _id in req.body. which is wrong

Comment: either change you get request to post in server file and service file both or try to pass _id in req.params or req.query

Comment: You should follow the REST architecture and pass the `id` in the `req.params.id` That is, your url should be `this.apiUrl + "/category/posts/" + _id`. Also, your are currently never passing over the _id in any way to the server.

Answer (score 0):

your api method is get method and you want _id in req.body. which is wrong.
you need to either change you get request to post in server file and service file both or try to pass _id in req.params or req.query:-

**If you pass _id as req.query :-**

your server code will be like:-

```
app.get('/api/category/posts', (req, res) => {
    Post.find({ categoryId: req.query._id }, function(err, posts) {
        res.json(posts);
    });
});
```

service file

```
getPosts(_id): Observable<Post[]>{
            return this.http.get<Post[]>(this.apiUrl +"/category/posts"+'?_id='+_id);
              }
```

component.ts will be same.

**and if you want to use post method to check for req.body then your code will be changed as following:-**

your server code will be like:-

```
app.post('/api/category/posts', (req, res) => {
    Post.find({ categoryId: req.body._id }, function(err, posts) {
        res.json(posts);
    }); });
```

service file

```
getPosts(_id): Observable<Post[]>{
            return this.http.post<Post[]>(this.apiUrl +"/category/posts",{_id:_id});
              }
```

component.ts will be same.

Answer (score 0):

Following [REST](https://spring.io/understanding/REST) architecture to get resources, you should pass the the _id in the get request parameters. You can also validate your `id` parameter making sure the passed `id` is a number using a simple regex pattern

Express route

```
app.get('/api/category/posts/:id(\\d+)', (req, res) => {
    Post.find({ categoryId: req.params.id }, function(err, posts) {
        res.json(posts);
    });
});
```

service file

```
getPosts(_id): Observable<Post[]>{
    return this.http.get<Post[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/category/posts/${_id}`);
}
```

component file

```
this.appService.getPosts(_id)
    .subscribe(data =>this.posts=data);
```

As a good practice, you should also keep track of your subscriptions and unsubscribe from them when you are done or on component destroy, or use the `first` operator to unsubscribe after first subscription.